# android Mediarecorder send videostream over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

i want to send android camera video over bluetooth to the PC. but it seems there is no way of sending video over bluetooth in android.

Comment: Can you expand this into a question?  What have you tried, if anything?

Comment: I have implemented getting bytes from camera preview , then encoded to jpeg and sending via Bluetooth to my pc where the application displays it image by image ... But I want to send streaming video from Android camera to the pc instead of images ...

Answer (score 1):

I would say for STREAMING this is not possible.
The bandwidth of bluetooth isn't large enough.
Please see: [www.palowireless.com/bluetooth/docs/mmichthesis.pdf](http://www.palowireless.com/bluetooth/docs/mmichthesis.pdf)

... up to 432kbps symmetrical, 721/57.6kbps asymmetrical.

Most cameras in recent Android devices are 5 megapixel or greater. The video generated from these cameras is much too large for the bluetooth pipe. Some front facing cameras are less (1 megapixel or so) but even this would be pushing or exceeding the bluetooth limitations.

I don't have a front facing camera on my phone, but I took a 60 second video with my phone on two settings (the highest quality and the lowest):

"HD": (1280x720) : 42 MBytes ... 42x8 = 336 Mbits  ... / 60 seconds = 5.6 Mbit/s

"Youtube" (720x480) : 21 MBytes ... 21x8 = 168 Mbits ... / 60 seconds = 2.8 Mbits/s

---

According to: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

### There are 3 encoding settings. The middle one would be almost equal to the max datarate for bluetooth (according to mmichthesis.pdf), you probably don't want to be on the verge of maxing out the hardware. The lowest one is probably your safe bet, but it's only 12 FPS and a terribly small resolution (176 x 144). The lowest setting would definitely work, though.

Also, there are FFMPEG builds available for Android, so you could encode the video to custom settings (somewhere between the lowest and the middle encoding setting on the second link) but this would be a bit more work.

Comment: BTW, I have a T-Mobile G2 ... also known as Desire Z outside the USA

Comment: Braden thanks! So it means I should give up my dream of video streaming by Bluetooth ? but I have seen a paper explaining how to do it on a Nokia phone. If I use a lower resolution for camera settings would that be possible ?

Comment: Can H.263 come to my rescue ?

Comment: Ah yes, I made the assumption that you'd only be able to record using the same encoding settings available to the camera. There is a much lower one that would work perfectly for you (56 kbps video and 24kbps audio).
Please see: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html     (at the bottom).

I think your dream is completely possible :)

Comment: You don't want to use H.263 as you're limited on bandwidth. H.264 has a much higher compression ratio.

Comment: But how to stream using Bluetooth... Android seems to support video support only via RTSP or HTTP !

Comment: I've given a little push in the right direction, but eventually some research/thinking is going to be required. Best of luck!